# How to customize a Netdata dashboard Chart

Tags: ubuntu, netdata

I have created a simple dashboard chart in Netdata to graph traffic at interface ens160

```
        <div data-netdata="net.ens160"
                data-title="ens160 (Native)"
                data-chart-library="dygraph"
                data-width="90%"
                data-height="100%"
                data-after="-300"
                ></div>
```

It displays a graph with both incoming and outgoing traffic. However what I need is to graph only the incoming traffic, is there a way to expand the "net.ens160" to show more specific information? or do I need a different approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I needed to add the "data-dimensions" statement to indicate incoming or outgoing traffic.